# A simple question about rational Hodge conjecture

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, hodge-theory

Good evening everyone :

In the link [here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8LddfdeBbHgC&pg=PA1121&lpg=PA1121&dq=if+all+Hodge+classes+are+generated+by+the+Hodge+classes+of+divisors,+then+the+Hodge+conjecture+is+true&source=bl&ots=QH63Af04Lp&sig=uK1_tUuPJSNgKDbdKsxHQg-TsHs&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=r6AEVfDbHsHlUozIgfgB&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=if%20all%20Hodge%20classes%20are%20generated%20by%20the%20Hodge%20classes%20of%20divisors%2C%20then%20the%20Hodge%20conjecture%20is%20true&f=false)
I found the following sentence : 
The Hodge conjecture predicts that the $\mathbb{Q}$ - linear span of the classes of algebraic subvarities in the cohomology of a smooth complex projective variety $X$ is given by the Hodge ring : $ \mathrm{Hdg} (X) = \displaystyle \bigoplus_p H^{2p} ( X, \mathbb{Q} ) \bigcap H^{p,p} ( X , \mathbb{C} ) $. The elements of this ring being called Hodge cycles. For elements of $ H^2 ( X, \mathbb{Q} ) $ this is a result of Lefschetz. **It follows that if the Hodge ring of $X$ is generated by its elements of degree $2$, then the Hodge conjecture is true for $X$, and all algebraic classes represent intersections of divisors.**

My question is :

What is concretly, the meaning of the last sentence as follows : 
if the Hodge ring of $X$ is generated by its elements of degree $2$, then the Hodge conjecture is true for $X$, and all algebraic classes represent intersections of divisors.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but perhaps it's because we have Lefschetz $(1,1)$?

Comment: Alex : I don't understand precisely how is defined the surjective map : $ \langle \ \mathrm{Hdg}^1(X) \ \rangle \to \mathrm{Hdg} (X) $ as it's said in that sentence : "It follows that if the Hodge ring of $X$ is generated by its elements of degree $2$, then the Hodge conjecture is true for $X$". I also try to understand the meaning of : "all algebraic classes represent intersections of divisors", but i'm not able to understand it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If The Hodge ring is generated in degree 1, then $Hdg(X)=<Hdg^1(X)>$, so any Hodge class can be written as a finite sum of products of (1,1)-classes, or equivalently, as Alex Youcis points out, products of classes of divisors. Hence the Hodge conjecture holds. The surjective map you are talking about is the map $Hdg^1(X)\otimes \cdots \otimes Hdg^1(X) \to Hdg^k(X)$, taking a sum of tensor products to its cycle class via intersection product.